# Logic of name_to_handle_at()

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am not getting much information on the new system call name_to_handle_at() and open_to_handle_at(). Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks

An Edit. I just have this

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.man/2158

Comment: can you give us a link or quote to show the context where it is used?

Comment: It's a "new"-ish Linux kernel feature dealing with file handles. Nobody really talks about it much anywhere. I'd personally love it if a kernel dev or whatnot could answer this in-depth.

Answer (score 6):

These functions are useful for writing user space servers.

For example, when implementing the NFS protocol, which does not have the 'open' concept, or a file descriptor, but instead relies on a persistent file identifier, the name_to_handle_at function can be used to generate this persistent handle in a portable way.

It then gets sent to the client, which will return it back to the server at a later point.
The server can then use open_to_handle_at to perform the operation.

One could ask how this is better than simply sending the full path name between client and server.
A number of options:

- The file system can use internal (more compact) representations
  instead of the file name   (for example based on inode).
- When going from the handle to file descriptor, potentially less
  work needs to be done.   (no more path traversal)
- In the scenario given above, resource consumption on the server is reduced (no need to keep track of open file descriptors on the server side)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to assume that those functions are needed to support some or all of the `*at()` functions added to POSIX 2008, such as [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html):

> ```
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int openat(int fd, const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> The `openat()` function shall be equivalent to the `open()` function except in the case where path specifies a relative path. In this case the file to be opened is determined relative to the directory associated with the file descriptor `fd` instead of the current working directory. If the file descriptor was opened without `O_SEARCH`, the function shall check whether directory searches are permitted using the current permissions of the directory underlying the file descriptor. If the file descriptor was opened with `O_SEARCH`, the function shall not perform the check.

Related functions include:

- [`faccessat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/faccessat.html)
- [`fchmodat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmodat.html)
- [`fchownat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchownat.html)
- [`fstatat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html)
- [`linkat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/linkat.html)
- [`mkdirat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdirat.html)
- [`mkfifoat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifoat.html)
- [`mknodat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknodat.html)
- [`readlinkat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlinkat.html)
- [`renameat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/renameat.html)
- [`symlinkat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlinkat.html)
- [`unlinkat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlinkat.html)